# How to convert string to integer in java as well as android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a `String` to an `Integer`.  I've used

```
int n1 = Integer.valueOf(s1,10);
```

and I also tried

```
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1,10);
```

but I'm getting the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.anmol.calc, PID: 19430
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 10-25 14:28:26.630 19430-19430/com.example.anmol.calc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 14:28:26.630 19430-19430/com.example.anmol.calc E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.anmol.calc, PID: 19430
10-25 14:28:26.630 19430-19430/com.example.anmol.calc E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
10-25 14:28:26.630 19430-19430/com.example.anmol.calc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-25 14:28:26.630 19430-19430/com.example.anmol.calc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)

Comment: Because your String doesn't  have a **valid** number format.

Comment: Your variable `s1` is empty, the empty string `""`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

because the empty `String` isn't an `int`.  You can test that the `String` contains digits with a regular expression (`\\d+` is one or more digit). Something like,

```
int n1 = 0;
if (s1 != null && s1.matches("\\d+")) {
    n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
}
```

You could als write that with a ternary. Like,

```
int n1 = (s1 == null || !s1.matches("\\d+")) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(s1);
```